Why doesn't my microphone amplifier work?
I designed a microphone amplifier like in the simulation image below. The images of it in real life are also below. The microphone is a JLI2555. The input voltage used in the simulation is 1mV.
When I connect the headphones as seen in the picture below I do not hear anything but a periodically beeping sound. When I measure the ouput with my voltmeter I see the DC voltage of 7.5 volts. The supply voltage comes from two 9 volt batteries. In the simulation a 15 volt suppy is used.
What could be wrong with this circuit?








The schematic indicates that the positive and negative inputs of the op-amp are shorted together.

They are crossed not shorted

schematic works the one i made irl doesnt

The schematic is unreadable. Use the schematic drawing tool on this forum to redraw the schematic as you have wired it including the polarity of the capacitors. You could have a wiring issue or a backwards capacitor. Also, the JFET is probably not biased properly and probably in cut-off. Try see if your circuit works without the JFET preamp (opamp only). Bypass the power supply near the opamp with a 1 uF capacitor.

@LEXORAI You apparently have a 2-terminal condenser mic (no internal jfet as commonly used in 3-terminal cheap electrets.) You should carefully examine the necessary kind of circuit, such as found discussed here as a Schoeps (or Schöps) circuit. Driving a FET in a simulation using an ideal voltage source isn't going to give you anything like IRL. You should not have expected it to do so at the outset. You really should be asking for pre-amplifier help. You need to understand your transducer.

Which op-amp was used on the IRL breadboard circuit? There's so many types and not all will work.

@LEXORAI Here's a site that makes some important points. Read through it, please.

Op amp used was TL071cp

What test equipment do you have?  Do you have any of the following: Signal generator, voltmeter, current meter, scope.

I only have a multimeter

I found the solution. The reason is you need a 1G OHm resistor in parallel with the mic capsule and JFET. Also a capacitor with the resistor to form a filter at the gate of the JFET. My Gate was hanging in the air and not connected to ground in the circuit. I thought it was connected to ground through the mic capsule

Let's assume your amp circuit has only well working parts and it's connected as your schematic shows. It has a common cathode fet amp which  can have voltage gain as much as = 10 and then there's another amp which has voltage gain about =100. The total voltage gain is 1000. Maybe your fet is not as steep as I imagined, but the total voltage gain can still be hundreds.
Your breadboard construction is the birthplace of nightmares. I guess it generates via the power supply lines and unwanted capacitances so much feedback that the circuit is an oscillator. I have NEVER succeeded to make an amplifier with voltage gain this high otherwise than by dividing the amplification to more stages which all are properly wired and decoupled to prevent feedback. Decoupling needs as a minimum a big enough capacitor between the poles of the DC supply, as near the amp as possible, often more effective filtering is needed for the 1st amp stage.
Do the same.
BTW your 1st fet stage doesn't obey what's suggested in the datasheet. You have the (commonly used) common cathode amp stage. The datasheet suggests no-voltage-gain cathode follower.
You should really learn how to proceed the fault finding. Test at first the opamp circuit. Then add the fet amp & test the result. Finally add the mic. If you cannot invent any surely working test signal source with known output voltage you are in a trouble. The problem is not unsolvable. One can either have purchased proper electronics lab instruments or he can build something. Here's a simple wide band signal generator which has well controlled 1.5 mV peak to peak output voltage and manually adjustable frequency:

The signal unfortunately isn't a sinewave, but it should be easy to hear if it's fed to an audio system which has enough gain.
(the obligatory part: The attached image and all its parts are 100% drawn by me for this answer)

Why will a decoupling capacitor prevent oscillation? And do i then build two op amp stages each with less amplification?

Your battery voltage swings a little up and down due the changes of the current the opamp takes. The drop happens inside the battery and in the wires which have resistance and inductance. High capacitance shorts the caused AC voltage. One must often have in parallel an electrolytic and ceramic capacitor due the high inductance of the electrolytic capacitors. As you see the AC component in your DC voltage is fed directly to the input of your opamp. Opamp itself maybe stays stable when decoupled, but the fet stage and the opamp biasing needs different RC lowpass filtering to the DC voltage.

(Continued) 2 amplification stages, both with voltage gain say 33 would be easier.

I already tried adding capacitors to op amp as seen in schematic, so i also need to add two decoupling capacitors to the voltage source and make the entire thing have two stages? Why would two stages make any difference though? And where exactly are these parasitic capacitances located are they between the individual rails of the breadboard?

@LEXORAI 1) The 1st opamp stage and the fet stage can have separately filtered operating voltages, 2) the DC current of the 2nd opamp stage need not to go through the qround wiring of the 1st opamp stage and the fet stage,3) the 1st opamp and the fet stage can be in a separate metal can.

What do you mean by "separately filtered operating voltages" and "the 1st opamp and the fet stage can be in a separate metal can"?

@LEXORAI Feed the operating voltage through a stabilizer or lowpass filter, make a metal box around the fet and 1st opamp stage, Decoupling is a part of the filtering. Let the mic capsule be inside the same grounded metal box, so do not forget leave holes for the sound. Also most mic manufacturers remember to include them. They are the gaps between the wires of the grill in front of the mic capsule. Your photos show no hint of any attempts to shield the capsule and the amp.

What does shielding with the metal box do other then EM interfereence blocking?

@LEXORAI Feedback from output to input via fields is EM interference. Your long wires and breadboard conductor stripes can capture it due the high impedance in the input. It's possible that no single feedback route alone is strong enough to make the amp to oscillate, but all together can be different. I suspect feedback through DC supply lines is in this case the strongest route. When your amp starts to work you may well start to need the shielding just to keep the audio clean of external noises.

I tried with two op amp stages. First op amp has Amplification(invertin op amp) of 10 (10k resistor/1k resistor) it has a capacitor of 10uF in series with the 1k resistor the output of the 1st op amp goes into the input of the second which has identical resistors and a 10uF capacitor at the input. At the start of the circuit is the JFET with 100 Ohm resistor at its drain and a 100Kohm resistor between source and base with a 10000 pF capacitor connecting the 100kOhm resistor at the gate with the mic capsule. The output of the second op amp also has a 10uF capacitor.

This circuit worked a little bit poorly and then it does not work again and works again. Completely random and no logic. I forgot to mention there is also a 10000pF capacitor between voltage DC source and ground

Probably the DC voltage on the gate of your input transistor is wrong.
It is unclear whether the microphone will automatically deliver an appropriate DC biasing.
So maybe you need a series C there and then one or two resistors to bias the gate.
You should check the drain voltage to see if the right current is flowing. Probably the drain shuld be around half the supply voltage. If you are not sure, just experiment with different gate biasing voltages.
